# Combinatorics: Find the total number of combinations! OR a formula to quantify the number of solution

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set $N = \{1,2,3,..., N\}$ and a size $n$ to be the number of dimensions. Generally, $N > n$.

For example, $N = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $n = 4$.
Set A is the solution set containing all the possible combinations that doesn't violate the rule: for each element in A, no more than 1 dimensions(slots) can have the same number.

In the case of $ n = 4, N = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, each element in A has a dimension of 4.

$A = \{[1, 2, 3, 4],
      [1, 1, 4, 5], 
     [5, 5, 5, 5],
     [3, 3, 3, 3],...\}$

But [1, 3, 3, 5] is not allowed in the solution set, since it violates the condition that no more than 1 dimension can have the same number, i.e., [**1**, 3, **3**, 5] has conflicts on dimension 1 and 3 with respect to [**1**, 2, **3**, 4].

Here is my try:

case1: the elements in set A all have different numbers on each dimension: $NPn = \frac{N!}{(N-n)!}$;

case2: there is 1 repeated number in the solution, in the case of N = 5, n=4 i.e., [1,1,2,3],[2,1,1,3], etc.
The number of solutions becomes $N\times\frac{(N-1)!}{(N-1-n-2)!}\times(n-2+1) + (N-1)\times\frac{(N-1-1)!}{(N-1-1-n-2)!}\times(n-2+1)+ ... +(N-k)\times\frac{(N-(k+1))!}{(N-k-n-2)!}\times(n-2+1)$.

I'll say a little more about this. Fix the number to be repeated and the rest of the $n-2$ places uses permutation again and insert the repeated block in the $n-2+1$ places. Last but not the least, for the sake of simplicity, I matched the next solution to use the different number to align the repeated $A1$ element and once the repetition is fixed, the rest follows the similar idea. And I tried the group-and-insert technique for repetition size bigger than 2.

I am sure I missed some counts, but is there any better way to do that. Thanks in ahead.

Comment: I (also) am confused. [1,3,3,5] does not "violate the condition that no more than 2 dimensions can have the same number", since only the 1st and 3rd elements have a value matching the *dimension #* (presumably) assigned to the corresponding slot.

Comment: Do you instead intend that *no more than 1 dimension can have the same number*?

Comment: Are you looking for the largest possible set $A\subseteq\{1,...,N\}^n$ with the property that for every $x,y\in A$ with $x\ne y$, there is at most one $i$ such that $x_i=y_i$?

Comment: @Karl I would say yes!

Comment: @user2661923 yes!

Comment: Your question is a **very complicated variation** of [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), that makes my head hurt.  I don't know if your analysis is right or not.  Have you checked individual situations (e.g. $N=6, n=3,~~$ and $~~N=5,n=3$) **manually** to see if your Case 1 and Case 2 results agree with the formulas that you have derived?  Also, starting with Case 1, which is the simpler case, it would help if you provided a lot of detail on how you derived that formula (**after you do the manual checking**).

Comment: For what it's worth, if I was attacking this problem, because of how complicated it seems to me, my **first move** would be to write and run a computer program that checked $N \in \{4,5,6,7,8,9,10\},~n \in \{3,4,5,6\}$ such that $n < N.$  Use something like C, Java, Python, or whatever language you know.  If your analytical and computer-simulated results disagree, then you have to explain to yourself where the mistake is.  This is known as **sanity-checking**.  In fact, I would write and run **two separate** programs, one to cover Case 1, and one to cover Case 2.

Comment: Why is $[1,2,3,4]$ allowed?

Comment: @user why it's not? It does not violate anything.

Comment: @user2661923 I'll take a look into this!!

Comment: @RichZhang It has 1 in the first position and 3 in the third position.

Comment: @user as an element itself, it is ok to have 1 at position 1 and 3 at position, actually for the first element it can be any combinations, but anything after that it needs to follow the rules.